# openssl -showcerts with -servername gives wrong anchor/root?

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

Despite reading multiple SO posts on this topic ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server) and [eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420694/openssl-shows-a-different-server-certificate-while-browser-shows-correctly)), `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername` downloads the wrong anchor/root certificate, whereas my web browser shows the correct anchor/root certificate.

```
# get the chain of certs
[root@server dir]# openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -servername www.google.com -showcerts 2>&1 < /dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > chain.pem
[root@server dir]#

# save the chain's certs to files: cert.pem (client/leaf) cert1.pem cert2.pem
[root@server dir]# cat chain.pem | awk 'split_after == 1 {n++;split_after=0} /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {split_after=1} {print > "cert" n ".pem"}'
[root@server dir]#

# verify fails
[root@server dir]# openssl verify -trusted cert2.pem -untrusted cert1.pem cert.pem                                           
cert.pem: C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
error 2 at 2 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate

# verify succeeds
# openssl verify -trusted ANCHOR-FROM-BROWSER.PEM -untrusted cert1.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK
```

Firefox rightly says that Google's anchor/root PEM contains "AocvmM" but openssl can't find it (BTW, same behavior in CentOS 7.4 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS):

```
[root@server dir]# openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -showcerts -servername www.google.com 2>&1 < /dev/null | grep AocvmM
[root@server dir]#
```

Question: Why doesn't -showcerts display the *correct* anchor/root certificate?
 Put another way, which certificate is -showcerts displaying, if it's not the anchor/root?

Comment: I didn't fully comprehend what you are actually asking. Could you clarify please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of certs included in the "bundle" (the file with the chain of certs) is decided by the Web Server (probably Apache) that serves the page. Whether s_client (or openssl in general) receives the correct and complete list is nothing that openssl has any control about.

You need the root certificate [available at this site](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/604.html).

Copy the text including from

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

until

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

to a file called `equifax.pem`

Then, verify the whole chain:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile equifax.pem -untrusted cert1.pem -untrusted cert2.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK
```

---

#### Edit

If the equifax cert is in the default local ssl cert repository (/etc/ssl/certs/) then, this will also work:

```
$ openssl verify -untrusted cert1.pem -untrusted cert2.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK
```

That the equifax cert is or is not at the ssl certs directory is a separate problem. You may update it.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I think I figured this out: (1) there's a GitHub issue about the misleading man page: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/4933 and (2) -showcerts didn't download the *entire* chain since cert2.pem was NOT the anchor/root because *its* Issuer is Equifax. To test, I downloaded equifax.pem and did `cat cert1.pem cert2.pem > intermediates.pem` followed by `openssl verify -trusted equifax.pem -untrusted intermediates.pem cert.pem`. Result: `cert.pem: OK` @isaac